# Can I swap a HDD from a RAID 1 for a bigger capacity drive?

Tags: raid

I have a RAID 1 setup with two 500GB drives. So they mirror each other. I know that if I take one of them out and put in a new 500GB drive it will set it up so that the new drive will mirror the old one.

My question is if I take out one of the 500GB drives and add say a 2TB drive, will it set up the 2TB drive to mirror the 500GB? I assume if it does, it will only allow me access to 500GB. However, if I then take out the one remaining 500GB after the data has been mirrored and stick in a 2TB, once that is rebuilt, will I then have a 2TB RAID setup with the same data as what was originally on the 2x 500GB setup?

Answer (score 3):

Most hardware controllers require you to recreate the volume. This means backup, delete, create and restore backups. Some may allow to grow the volume but not even all the latest controllers do that.

Then if you have some brand hardware, such as HP enclosure or Terastation NAS, it is possible you cannot ever get more space.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your raid controller, but in theory that should workfor most controllers. So you would then have 1.5TB of space on each drive left to allocate somewhere. You can try striping them for speed, mirroring for fault tolerance, or just use them as disks